# Cycles Render showing up white

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I switched to "Cycles Render" instead of "Blender Render" and my object is now fully white. I would like to render my object with it's material. I have been looking for solutions for quite some time and I'm not quite sure. [image]

Answer (score 3):

You have probably setup your materials for the Blender Render which are not compatible with Cycles. That means you'll have to (re-)create the materials for Cycles.